# WebSocket server implementation on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, websocket

I want to implement a WebSocket server on iOS and the client side on the browser. I found this library [for server side implementation in objective c](https://github.com/mirek/CoreWebSocket).

I'm having trouble building the project and need help urgently. I followed the steps as given in *installation guide*

1. Add CoreWebSocket.xcodeproj to project
2. In to targets Build Phases

   - In Target Dependencies add CoreWebSocket
   - In Link Binary With Libraries add

     - CFNetwork.framework
     - CoreServices.framework --------------- `//Could not add this for iOS`
     - libcrypto.dylib --------------- `//Could not add this for iOS`
     - CoreWebSocket.framework
   - Add Build Phase > Add Copy Files Set

     - Destination to be Frameworks
     - Add CoreWebSocket.framework
3. Clean
4. Build CoreWebSocket --------------- `//Build is targeted to Mac OS X`
5. Build your app --------------- `//Build fails here`

### Result after step #3

[image: Final result after step #3]

**FOR STEP #4** I selected CoreWebSocket and did a clean and build which was successful. 
[image: Step #4]

But when I selected my project again ***(ServerSockTrial)*** and built it I got this linker error.

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServerSockTrial-bnacsspxhqhmlcgtflolkhxivmrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreWebSocket/CoreWebSocket'

[image]

If for step 4 I selected CoreWebSocket_iOS and build I get this linker error ->

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/administrator/Desktop/tushar/Smart Tv/CoreWebSocket-master/CoreWebSocket_iOS/CoreWebSocket_iOS-Prefix.pch'
>   clang: error: no input files
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Can anyone pls help?

Comment: downvoter care to explain? I'd like to know what i did wrong here to rectify myself.

Comment: Down Vote abusers. Welcome to SO.